# Authorities communicating to other authorities an individual's data

Tags: citizenship

My father told me that when I was given Italian citizenship at the age of 18, Italian authorities communicated to my origin's country that I took Italian citizenship.
But does it work that way generally speaking?
I don't know whether it is true and whether it's a result of particular bilateral relationships if the former applies, but is it normal practice in other countries like the UK or US to communicate to an individual's country of origin that such applicant was conferred citizenship?
I might expect that this happened in my case, since Italy and my parents' country are peculiarly untrasparent, but what about the rest of the countries?

Answer (score 2):

Such a thing would be very unusual. Perhaps the two countries have some very peculiar arrangement, but if that's the case, it's specific to them. Citizenship is a very pure representation of the sovereignty of a nation, and none feel any obligation to transmit such information, upon its acquisition, to any other nation on Earth - neither by any international tradition or understanding, and certainly by any kind of international agreement. That's not to say that a country wouldn't inform another nation that asked, and without hesitation. It's not meant to be a secret.

From personal experience, I can tell you that the UK and US don't share such information unless one or the other enquires about it.

Comment: Well I don't really know either...but I know that Italy and this country both have peculiar and too outreaching ways of managing things. I mean, this thing wouldn't happen between of said countries and another one like France or US, so for istance there would not be such a thing for an Italian who laterwards took US citizenship or a guy from my origin country taking UK or French citizenship, but as for Italy and this country, my father told me this. I'm not really of what he said but I have to ask, and if that really happened, I would not be surprised, since the nature of these 2 countries.

Comment: He told me that authorities eventually informed the Italian Embassy in this country that further informed these other authorities.

Comment: I mean, I told him that's highly unlikely but he insisted that it was the case.

Comment: Just because your father is certain doesn't mean he's correct.

Comment: Exactly, but I wouldn't even unconsider it given the strange laws or practices that Italian law is up to. An example could be that they recently started to ask coucil house immigrant applicants estate declaration from their home countries, so this is very outreaching